# How to connect to LinkedIn REST API with python?

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm newbie in programming so please excuse me. To access LinkedIn I was using python-linkedin library but because some changes from LinkedIn, this library is not working anymore. What would be the best workaround for this?

Comment: Upgrade the library ? Update the library ? Change the library ?

Comment: The library is not updated for 3 years and I did not find a proper library too.

Comment: Update the library != Wait for the library to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Just generate you API keys on linkedin website https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 and then I’d recommend using vanilla python for writing your http clients to call the LinkedinAPIs through http (rest). In this way you won’t be relying on any library

Comment: @Mahdi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183197/getting-oauth-access-token-for-linkedin-using-python-linkedin-library. Also have a look at this link.